# PHP prevent calling all function in a class when a condition is not met

Tags: php

Suppose i have two classes and i need to call one method from another class if there is a speciific condition is met(i.e: If a gateway is active)

Suppose i have `Stripe` class and a method in it called `createProduct()`. I have another class `Payment` and i want to call that method (createProduct()) from `Payment` class and there will be no error.

```
<?php
   class Stripe(){
        public function __construct(){
             if( !$active_stripe ) return;
        }
        public function createproduct(){
             //... Stuffs to create a product
        }
   }     


<?php
   class Payment(){
        public $stripe;
        public function __construct(){
             $this->stripe = new Stripe();
        }
        public function fnCreateproduct(){
             $prod = $this->stripe->createProduct();
        }
   }
```

Though i am checking is stripe active in __construct fn in first class the createproduct() is still being called.

Comment: You need `global $active_stripe;` to access a global variable.

Comment: Is there other code in `__construct()` that runs after the `return` when Stripe is active?

Comment: The constructor always returns an instance of the class, your `if` statement doesn't prevent that. The only way to stop it is to throw an exception. And then you need to use `try/catch` in `Payment::__construct()` to skip over the assignment to `$this->stripe`.

Comment: And then you'll need to check if `$this->stripe` is set in `fnCreateproduct()`.

Comment: Why not to pass the $active_stripe to your Stripe class constructor? and based on it prevent the specific action

Answer (score 1):

"returning" from a constructor is not good.

I suppose `$active_stripe` is globally available.

The quickest answer to your question might be a quick and dirty fix:

```php
<?php
   class Stripe(){
        public function __construct(){
             // if( !$active_stripe ) return; // <-- move this
        }
        public function createproduct(){
             //... Stuffs to create a product
        }
   }     


<?php
   class Payment(){
        public $stripe;
        public function __construct(){
             $this->stripe = new Stripe();
        }
        public function fnCreateproduct(){
             if( !$active_stripe ) return; // <-- here!!!
             $prod = $this->stripe->createProduct();
        }
   }
```